# LiveData not getting observed in case of set or post value

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata

I am observing live data from the repository to view model but I am not getting any callback. Why is this so?

**MyViewModel.kt**

```
fun incrementPoints(userPoints: UserPoints): LiveData<NetworkResource<StatusResponse>> {
        var callbackObserver = MutableLiveData<NetworkResource<StatusResponse>>()
        IncrementPointsRepository.incrementPoints(userPoints).observeForever {
            //not getting any callback here
            callbackObserver.value = it
        }
        return callbackObserver
    }
```

**Repository.kt**

```
object IncrementPointsRepository {

    fun incrementPoints(userPoints: UserPoints): LiveData<NetworkResource<StatusResponse>> {
        val callbackObserver = MutableLiveData<NetworkResource<StatusResponse>>()
        val destinationService = ServiceBuilder.buildService(DestinationService::class.java)
        val requestCall = destinationService.incrementPoints(userPoints)
        requestCall.enqueue(object : Callback<StatusResponse> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<StatusResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                callbackObserver.value = NetworkResource.error(t)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<StatusResponse>, response: Response<StatusResponse>) {
                //this is getting called
                callbackObserver.value = NetworkResource.success(response)
            }
        })
        return callbackObserver
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

incrementPoints function was called from another thread so it wasn't getting observed.

activity.runOnUiThread resolved this